# Maximal principal ideal which is not maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove that in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ the ideal generated by $X$, i.e. $I=\langle X\rangle$, is a **maximal principal ideal** (that is, maximal among principal ideals), but is not a **maximal ideal**.

Comment: $I=\langle X\rangle \subsetneq \langle 2,X\rangle$, so it is not maximal.

Comment: Why post in the imperative? Are you assigning homework to us?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I did not intend that.

Comment: but why $<X>$ is a maximal ideal principal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "maximal ideal principal". Could you define it?

Comment: I think it's [romance language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_language) word order for "maximal principal ideal", i.e. ideal which is maximal among principal ideals.

Comment: I mean in all principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ then $<X>$ is maximal. OK?

Comment: I think if $<h[X]>$ is another principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ then $<h[X]>\subset <X>$. This mean if $f(X)\in <h(X)>$ then exits $g(X)$ s.t $f(X)=g(X).h(X)$, then what is $k(X)$ s.t $f(X)=x.k(X)$?.

Comment: Could you please use `\langle X\rangle` instead of `<X>`. I'm sure you can see the spacing is all wrong and it makes it *really* hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

$I$ is not maximal because it's contained in $\langle 2,X\rangle$, as [Sigur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31682/sigur) noticed, which is an  ideal which stricly contains $I$ and is itself strict.

But it's maximal among principal ideals. Indeed, let $I'$ a principal ideal containing $I$, say generated by $P_0$. If $P\in I'\setminus I$, we have $P(0)\neq 0$ (otherwise $P\in I$). Write $P:=\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^Na_jX^j}_{\in I\subset I'}+a_0$, then $a_0\in I'$. As $a_0=P_0Q_0$ for some $Q_0\in\Bbb Z[X]$, taking the degrees on both sided, $P_0$ is constant so $I'=\Bbb Z[X]$.

Conclusion: the only principal ideal containing $I$ is $\Bbb Z[X]$.

Comment: So, $\langle X\rangle \subset \langle 1\rangle$, and $\langle 1\rangle$ indeed principal ideal. Are we convention a ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ have to different $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?.

Comment: Not in the definition of an ideal, but in the definition of a maximal ideal yes.

Comment: OK, I see, thank you very much